# PHP - how to get mime type from getimagesize instead of a number

Tags: php, getimagesize

I am using PHP's [getimagesize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function to get the height/width/type from an image URL. Currently, for a jpg file, `$type` is returning `2`. How can I get it to return the actual mime type instead?

```
<?php
    list($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize('https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_51564349748_2ceac19a11_z_640_360_nofilter.jpg');
    echo 'Width: ' . $width . ' Height: ' . $height . ' Type: ' . $type;
```

This returns: `Width: 640 Height: 360 Type: 2`

Expected: `Width: 640 Height: 360 Type: image/jpeg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) is pretty clear about what the function returns. Looks like you need to assign the entire return value into a local variable (e.g. `$size = getimagesize(...)`, and then get the mime type from that like `$size['mime']`.

Comment: I saw that, I was just wondering if it was possible to do it using `list()` as opposed to assigning it to a variable. I will just go with that solution though. Thanks!

Comment: Since it's not a numeric key, I don't know if the order that fields come out in is reliable, or guaranteed not to change in a future version of PHP, for example. Something like `list($width, $height, $type, $mime) = array_values(getimagesize(...))` *might* work, but might also break randomly. I wouldn't trust it.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up! I agree, I will just stick with the recommendation in the documentation.